# Objectdeserialization over network

Tags: java, serialization, networking, sockets, messaging

i am getting an excepetion when i try to read an object from an ObjectInputStream via network like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
while ((Object o = ois.readObject()) != null) {
}
```

Here is the exception I get:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
```

The connection itself seems fine, since i am able to read strings via the network, but objects dont work.

Since it is an EOFExcepetion i assume that the stream currently sends no more data. (which is ok after the first object being sent).
so i was thinking maybe i am using objectdeserialization the wrong way?

what could be the problem here? thanks!

Comment: What does the server side look like? How do you end the connection?

Comment: the server does not end the connection. it serializes an object and then sends it to the client via outputstream.writeObject()

Comment: ok sorry, i just found out there was indeed a problem on the server where it was closing the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not call [available()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#available%28%29) to check whether there's stuff to read ? It's probably worth publishing your server side code. At the moment we're seeing only one side of the story.

Comment: but is this accurate? what if only half of the objects binary data is received yet? it will crash as soon as it reaches the end again.

Comment: I would expect readObject() to block until all the required data is present (unless something exceptional has occurred). Don't forget that under the covers you have TCP looking after data integrity and completeness for you.

Comment: ok i tried available() and it always seems to return 0, which would explain the EOFException. but how can i debug this? i am definitely sending an Object to the client, so it should be there.

Comment: Did you publish the server side ? That would be of help. On the server side are you closing and/or flushing the connection ?

Comment: thanks! yes, i am flushing after the writeObject() on the server side. also i can see the message on the client side when checking the socket's inputstream with an InputStreamReader instead of an ObjectInputStream. so the message and the object is definitely arriving on the client.

Comment: ok sorry, i just found out there was indeed a problem on the server where it was closing the connection.